# android different form layout_toLeftOf and layout_toStartOf?

Tags: android, layout

As the title say, what's the different form layout_toStartOf and layout_toLeftOf? Is the layout_toStartOf more efficiency?

Answer (score 3):

`layout_toStartOf` is related to localization. In some places, everything starts from right. `layout_toStartOf` is the same as `layout_toLeftOf` in most localization settings, while `layout_toStartOf` is kind of the opposite of `layout_toLeftOf` when the localization setting is set to Right to Left.

Update (for efficiency):

I do not think there will be any non-negligible difference in efficiency of performance. However, for the sake of localization (if to be supported), `layout_toStartOf` should always be favored over `layout_toLeftOf`.

Comment: I ask what's the different from the two attribute?!

Comment: @gekson For the first comment, I have edited my answer a little. If it is still not answering your question, please let me know. For the second comment, which part am I kidding?

Comment: thanks,but i know how to use attribute layout_toLeftOf and layout_toStartOf. I wonder whether layout_toStartOf is more efficiency?